# Move between two html page without losing JS context

Tags: javascript, html

I have two module let call it ModuleA and ModuleB
That are pure html/js/css without library.

The code is pretty separate for maintining purpose.

I want a ModuleManager page that load ModuleA and in some input go to ModuleB and then can rego on ModuleA

I have a jsScript on ModuleManager page and with `window.location.replace('./ModuleA/index.html')`
I can load my ModuleA or my ModuleB but after the replace my js script
who listen to `window.addEventListener('keydown')` from ModuleManager got disable because im not on ModuleManager page DOM anymore and this seem to destroy my js. A console log in while stop as soon as i replace.

At first i was staying on my ModuleManager page and loading MyModule as iframe

```
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="./ModuleA/index.html" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

But as my Iframe is the full page. And foreground the iframe specification make myListener not triggering event anymore as well.

A simple workAround is add inside ModuleA and ModuleB 2 keyDown Listener witch go to other module. But then my Module know each other and i don't like this. Because when il will add more module i don't want to add gestion in every existing module.

My folder kinda look like this

```
/(Folder /mysite.com)
|-->index.html (ModuleManager)
    |-->ModuleA (Folder)
        |--> index.html (ModuleA)
    |-->ModuleB (Folder)
        |--> index.html (ModuleB)
```

And module are accesible and working allAlone by mysite.com/ModuleA or ModuleA.mysite.com

ModuleA and ModuleB can be fullFonctionalSite with unlimited subfolder.
Usualy i would use nginx to a think like this but i want when on module Manage to keep a context et switch to a module or another seemlesly.

I also try to add all content of ModuleA/index.html inside a div in ContentManager. But ModuleA refere to a lot of ./thins.js ./subfolder/view.html and all this relative path got broke cause index.html include path context become /index.html and not /ModuleA/index.html

So it broke both Module and if i want to fix pathing like '/ModuleA/thing.js' in ModuleA/index.html it work for mysite.com/ModuleA/thing.js

But broke on ModuleA.mysite.com/thing.js

The way i see it tp make it possible is stay on the same page context all time. OR keeing a windows.JSManagerClass ok navigator.JSManagerClass that trigger a onLoad every time i change loc and register the keydown listener or keep it active

So anyway to manage this? What i want to do is it even possible?
Does some lib provide a thing like this? i could look at?
I feel like i miss the obvious way to do it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like you want to make a single page application (SPA).
If not, I'm sorry if I've misunderstood you.

There is a couple of great frameworks/libraries you can look into:

- React
- Vue
- Angular
- Svelte

Personally I know and use React.
I am not trying to be oppinionated, but since I don't know so much about the other frameworks, I can only speak for React.
Maybe someone else could talk about these or other frameworks/libraries and what makes them great/usefull?

A short and basic explanation about React:
It holds a single `index.html` file and all content is created with Javascript using an `html` -like syntax called `JSX`.
You can install a router (`react-router`) that handles routes/navigation between views/pages.
Because it is an SPA, you have "access" to all components (modules) at all times and makes the problems you deal with seem trivial.

The official site (where most, if not all examples are using old class based component syntax): [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org)

The official beta site for the newer function based component syntax (with hooks): [beta.reactjs.org](https://beta.reactjs.org/) (you should aim towards coding this way).

Comment: I think my first message is not clear enough the name module maybe is not appropiate the two app has no common ground the two are like two SPA app withouth React

My question is kinda like how i can have  htmll that switch between two react app(it is not react but the anwser is prob the same) Without losing my context. 

how to switch on command between two app isolated? One can be in react and the other in Vu for exemple.

Comment: Okay sorry about that, then it sounds to me that you are looking for a way to make data persist between two "websites"? If that is the case maybe look into `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`?

Comment: This store Data but not js context.

I kinda succeed with my first idea. Including Html of index.html in my page. 

Using import('ModuleA./main.js') instead of import default from 'ModuleA./main.js'
Seem to relocate context. ModuleA.js import seem to work with ./ and be in moduleA folder